# What is the URL structure of iOS delta updates?

Tags: ios, software-update, build-version

The over-the-air updates on iOS must come from some server similar to where the ipsw files are stored, does anyone know where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the build, version, and type of update. You can view a full list [here](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=OTA_Updates), however iOS 6 does not seem to be included currently, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Terrific! Thanks, my google searches just kept brining up blog articles... Yes, I was looking for the iOS 6 beta 2, since it's failed twice. I think I'll just get the ipsw...